# C# WPF DataGrid Change FontColour of Row Based on Value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm retrieving data from a Database and placing the contents into a WPF DataGrid like so;

namespace ContractsExcel
{
    public partial class UserSelection : Page
    {
        public UserSelection()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGrid.CanUserAddRows = false;
            string username = Environment.UserName;
            userImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\DanD\Desktop\" + username+".jpg"));
        }

```
    private void FillDataGrid(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbfString"].ConnectionString;
        using (OleDbConnection dbfCon = new OleDbConnection(constr))
        {
            try
            {
                dbfCon.Open();
                DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
                string dbfQuery = "SELECT em_pplid, em_name, em_netname FROM employs WHERE em_netname NOT LIKE ''";
                OleDbCommand MyQuery = new OleDbCommand(dbfQuery, dbfCon);
                OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter(MyQuery);
                DA.Fill(dTable);
                dataGrid.ItemsSource = dTable.AsDataView();
            }
            catch (OleDbException)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

What I would like to do is change the font colour of an entire row based on the contents of a row cell, for example if the order is cherished change the font colour of the row to red.

Whilst there are multiple questions about this topic existing already I couldn't find anything specific to this. Would this need to be done through XAML or C# and how woild I go about implementing this functionality?

Updated code with XAML;

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="0,0,10,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ColumnWidth="*" FontSize="18.667">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding em_netname}" Value='Chris'>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

Code to populate DataContext in C#;

namespace ContractsExcel
{
    public partial class UserSelection : Page
    {
        public UserSelection()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGrid.CanUserAddRows = false;
            string username = Environment.UserName;
            userImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\DanD\Desktop\" + username+".jpg"));
        }

```
    private void FillDataGrid(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbfString"].ConnectionString;
        using (OleDbConnection dbfCon = new OleDbConnection(constr))
        {
            try
            {
                dbfCon.Open();
                DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
                string dbfQuery = "SELECT em_pplid, em_name, em_netname FROM employs WHERE em_netname NOT LIKE ''";
                OleDbCommand MyQuery = new OleDbCommand(dbfQuery, dbfCon);
                OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter(MyQuery);
                DA.Fill(dTable);
                dataGrid.ItemsSource = dTable.AsDataView();
            }
            catch (OleDbException)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Style targetted to another type must be present within <DataGrid.Resources></DataGrid.Resources>.

Comment: Why are you changing style for `DataGridCell` if you want to change color for the entire row? That is NOT what i suggested..... Please look at my answer again.

Comment: @jstreet Apologies I have updated it now.

Comment: Ok, great, does it work now? What is `ItemsSource` binding to? Where's your `DataContext` ?

Comment: your XAML code is wrong, you cannot wrap `<Style>` in your `DataGrid`, it should be `<DataGrid.RowStyle>` or if you want some style for datagrid, it should be `<DataGrid.Style>`, otherwise it understands that you want to add the `Style` element as one item to the `Items` collection.

Comment: @CBreeze You have used style wrongly. Replace this <Style TargetType="DataGridRow"> with <DataGrid.RowStyle><Style> ...</Style></DataGrid.RowStyle> .

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm filling a DataTable through OleDB and FoxPro and setting `dataGrid.DataContext = dTable.DefaultView;` dTable is imply a DataTable that has been filled by OleDB

Comment: @CBreeze you simply are NOT using the working XAML i posted in my answer....

Comment: @jstreet I have updated it again, I am setting DataContext within C# instead of XAML

Comment: Where's your `DataContext` assigned now? Btw, removing target type is not going to accomplish anything.....

Comment: Ok, "withing C#" where exactly??? Again, post your actual code.....

Comment: @jstreet The issue I have with your code is I am unsure on how to build a DataContext within XAML using a DataTable populated through OleDB. As a non-working example this is what I am trying to achieve           <DataGrid.DataContext> <local:dTable.DefaultView/></DataGrid.DataContext>. If you look above in the comments you will see that I posted the code I am using to set the DataContext in C#

Comment: You don't need to build it within XAML, that's why i'm asking where you put it.... Again, the best place to put it would be in your window `Loaded` event.

Comment: AGAIN, where is that code placed in? What method? Once you're doing that in code behind, then take any `DataContext` assignment out of your XAML.

Comment: @jstreet entire code is posted above now to see where I am setting the DataContext in C#. However if I take the DataContext out of XAML there is no data in the table, and the same if I take it out of C# but leave it in XAML, there is no data...

Comment: I posted exactly what you have to do, please see my updated answer. You have to call `AsDataView() method.

Comment: @jstreet Doesn't work unfortunately, there is no data in my DataGrid at all now as soon as I remove `ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" ` from my XAML even after adding the method to the PageLoaded call.

Comment: Use `AsDataView()` method instead of `DefaultView` property. I just tried it and it works. Please try it.

Comment: @jstreet I'm using `dataGrid.DataContext = dTable.AsDataView();` and it is not working for me if I remove the XAML code `ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"`

Comment: You're using `Page` and I'm using `Window`.... That may be the problem... What platform are you in?

Comment: OK, i get it: do this then, `dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();`

Comment: Maybe but try my new suggestion.

Comment: Do this: `dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();`

Comment: @jstreet Well that has indeed removed the need to set it in XAML, however I am still not able to change the colour to red.. In `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="Name 3">` is the `Binding Name` simply the name of the column?

Comment: NO ! That is my SAMPLE `Model`.... You have to adjust to your model...

Comment: Just replace `Name` and `Name 3` with whatever you're binding to in your case....

Comment: `Name` you have to replace with the column name you want; and `Name 3` is the value(content) of that column you want to change color for.

Comment: @jstreet I understand that, I was asking that question within your context. Changing to `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding emnetname}" Value="Chris">` Where emnetname is the name of the column and Chris is a cell, it does not work..

Comment: your SQL statement uses `em_netname`, NOT `emnetname`....

Comment: @jstreet I thought that straight away, unfortunately neither makes a difference. What is really Strange is if I do it so that `Binding="{Binding em_pplid}" Value="1">` where of course that is an ID it works, it just doesn't work on em_name or em_netname!

Comment: well, there may be other issues but that does make a huge difference, you're binding to the wrong name..... can you see data in your data grid at all?

Comment: please update you XAML and SQL to be consistent with each other so people reading this aren't confused.

Comment: it is either `em_netname` or `emnetname` everywhere, you can't have both.

Comment: can you place a break point and verify the table actually has data before assigning `ItemsSource`?

Comment: Updated code for consistency. It works on the em_pplid just not on either of the names. Yes it does have Data before binding `ItemsSource`

Comment: Can you post a print screen of what you actually see, please?

Comment: @jstreet of what I see in the table? it's simply just one row highlited red when working on em_pplid but it is not highlited red when working on either of the name columns.

Comment: Yes, a print screen of your window containing the data grid, just like i did in my post.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need DataTriggers for such scenarios.
2. Changing Foreground of a DataGridCell will change that of entire row as style is applied to all cells.

Below style will make cherished order rows appear to be with Red font color and rest rows will have font color as Aqua.

```
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Aqua"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Order}" Value="Cherished">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Another approach is to use

```
           <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Aqua"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Title}" Value="Pepsi">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>

                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my code using your suggested answer however I am having the issue now of "Items collection must be empty before using item source". I have updated my code now with my XAML code, what do you suggest?

Comment: You have to put your style within <DataGrid.Resources><Style .../></DataGrid.Resources>, or you can write <DataGrid ...><DataGrid.RowStyle>...</DataGrid.RowStyle></DataGrid>, see my another approach in my answer.

Comment: Here style is targetted to DataGridCell so, we will put Style in <DataGrid.Resources>, if our Style is targetting DataGrid itself, we will use <DataGrid.Style>...</DataGrid.Style> .

Comment: hmm it is indeed setting all the fields to aqua but is still not setting my desired row to red... using this data binding: `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Title}" Value="Cherished">` where "Cherished" is the value of one cell in the column "netname". The columns are autogenerated, should I need to make them myself?

Comment: doesnt matter whether col.s are autogenerated or not

Answer (score -1):

write data template for data grid with custom colour for rows.
you are assigning data table directly to grid. so that you cannot change colour based on data.
else you have to write model class for colour then only can set colour based on data.

Comment: See my answer. DataTriggers are made for such scenarios. You can do the same with code too.